# What to use: sql==true vs sql===true?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

please, have a look here; and thanks all!
I am trying to create a system for upgrading buildings in my game. I made my upgrade div same for all buildings. When player click the build (div) run a function to appear a hide div filled by ajax post with the costs of upgrading. The class 'name'(same with the building name from db) of the div is sent to a php to get the required data. It works fine untill now... I added a click event to a button that should send the div 'name' into another php which should do the upgrade operation and echo "correct" in response ajax field. But when i click the btn, it show no log error... Error: SELECT ress1,ress2 FROM cost_cladiri WHERE building = 'camp_1' (I ve inserted a name of building from db instead of the variable(div name) to access the php directly, but the same error...
Here is my ajax and my php

```
    function getbuild(e) {  
  $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: '../account-handeling/get_cost_upgrade.php',
  data: {
  building: e.className,
},
  success: function (response){
   $('#display_cost').html(response); 
$("#increase").click(function(){  
    $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: '../account-handeling/upgrade_handle.php',
  data: {
  building: e.className,
}, 
  success: function (response){
   $('#display_cost').html(response);
  }
});
})  
       }
    });
  }
```

upgrade_handle.php

```
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
session_start();
}
$dbserver           = "localhost";
$dbusername         = "root";
$dbpassword         = "";
$db                 = "worlddomination";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$db);
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("No connection:".$conn->connect_error);
}

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
//$buildcost = $_POST['building'];

$sql    = "SELECT ress1,ress2 FROM cost_cladiri WHERE building = 'camp_1'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$ress1 = $row['ress1'];
$ress2 = $row['ress2'];
if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
    echo "$ress1";
}
else{
    echo "Error: ".$sql."<br/>".$conn->error;
}
```

What i ve done wrong? Thanks!!!

Comment: If you take out the AJAX and execute you get the same behavior?

Comment: i ve tried accessing the php direct link modifying  the variable with  camp_1. I think i have a problem in my sql, but is my 'all the time working ' sql expression... PS. I don t tried yet to delete the session cookie before access the php. I will try it when i m home. ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `select` query the `Mysqli::query` method will return mysqli_result object, so as it may be `== true` it wont be `=== true`.

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

I would try to check if it `!== false` or `instanceof mysqli_result`.

Edit: also you query the same thing two times, once object oriented and once procedural.

Comment: sorry, i am not well handeling  the terms. Can you explain please, where did I query the same thing 2 times?

Comment: One is `$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)` which is procedural style, and the other one is `$conn->query($sql)` inside the if, which is object oriented. You could use `$result` from procedural inside `if` instead of querying again.

Comment: i will try to apply your advices when i will be on pc and i will return with results. Thank you, sir !

Comment: It works!!! thank you for intervention and for help! here is my piece of code modified: please tell me if is the correct way:                                   if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$ress1 = $row['ress1'];
$ress2 = $row['ress2'];
 echo "$ress1";}

Comment: You should be ok, just those quotes surrounding variable when echoing, they're unnecessary.